# How to integrate Plurals from Lokalise in backbone application?

Tags: integration

I have existing web application based on backbone.js which is already using Lokalise for the localization. But, now I need to use the Plurals from the Localise.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Lokalise api just add the `plural_format` to the request, while exporting the project data. see [api documentation](https://lokalise.co/apidocs).